# Adding Bundles to existing ASP.NET Webforms solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, bundle

I am trying to add Bundles to an existing ASP.NET Webforms solution but my bundles always render empty and I am unsure why. I have been following [this blog post](http://igorzelmanovich.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/using-aspnet-bundling-and-minification.html).

So far I have:

- Added the Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework NuGet package
- Ensured required references are included
- Tried using debug="false" and debug="true" in Web.config
- Added the following code to my solution

**Global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

**App_Start/BundleConfig.cs**

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=303951
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Global").Include(
            "~/js/jquery-{version}.js",
            "~/js/jquery-ui.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/GlobalHead").Include(
            "~/js/modernizr*"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Global").Include(
            "~/css/site.css"));
    }
}
```

**Site.Master**

```
<head runat="server">
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundle/GlobalHead") %>
        <%: Styles.Render("~/Content/Global") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundle/Global") %>
</body>
```

**Web.Config**

```
<namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
</namespaces>
```

**Update**

To be clear, when I open a web page and inspect the resources with chrome dev tools, I can see

```
Content/Site.css
bundle/Global.js
bundle/GlobalHead.js
```

But when inspecting them they have no content.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Simple solution, I had some typing errors.

In the Site.Master I missed the 's' from the end of bundles. Making my Site.Master look like this.

```
<head runat="server">
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/GlobalHead") %>
        <%: Styles.Render("~/Content/Global") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Global") %>
</body>
```